# Test input box integer value for incrments of 100 and numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, and on the form I have an input box that can hold the value of an integer. When the user submits this form, it needs to first check in jQuery if the value of the input box is numeric as well as checking if it is in increments of 100.

So, if the user submits "hello" it will give an error. If the user types "1099" it will give an error. If the user types "1000" or "1100" it will give success.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(/^(\d*0|)0$/.test($('#inputId').val())){
    // numeric and multiple of 100
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLPag/#update)

Comment: I just noticed that if I put "a900" it submits the form.

Comment: @ChristianPage Is that with the edit? It works for this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BLPag/1/
Make sure you have the regex `^(\d*0|)0$` :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the input when you submit the form (or on an event such as `keyup` or `change` maybe), then validate with this function:

```
function isMultipleOf100(num) {
  return !isNaN(num) && num % 100 === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var x = $('input#myInput').val();
if(!isNaN(x)) {
    if(x % 100 === 0) {
        //valid
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, the `isNaN` check can be left out since `NaN % 100` is also `NaN` and `NaN !== 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of a regex and a modulus check...

```
check = 1000;

var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
if (intRegex.test(check)) {
    if (check % 100 === 0) {
        alert('Pass');
    } else {
        alert('Fail');
    }
}
```